# Finding minimal value in excel

Tags: excel

I have 5 lists in an excel file: `A2:A448,B2:B448,...,E2:E448`

The lists contain positive numbers.

I would like to be able to insert two numbers, let's say in cells `I4,J4`

Then, I want to find the row `X` such that the value `ABS(I4-AX)+ABS(J4-BX)` is minimal.

I need that the cell `I5` will contain `AX`, `J5` will contain `BX`, `K5` will contain `CX`, `L5` will contain `DX` and `M5` will contain `EX`.

Can anyone guide me please? I am a complete newbie in excel.

Comment: could you use VBA, but if you provide numerical example make solution imaginable

Comment: Would a helper column be allowed? If yes, use `ABS(I$4-A1)+ABS(J$4-B1)` and populate down, then get the `MATCH` of the `MIN`inum value: `=MATCH(MIN(F1:F6),F1:F6,0)` (assuming the helper column is `F`)

Comment: There are no limitations, this is just a part of a mini-project I am trying to start.